# Permission Denied when using mkdir() in Docker Terminal

Tags: python, windows, docker, mkdir

I am trying use Google Earth Engine's Python API on my 'Windows 10 Home' computer, for which Google recommend I set up a docker container (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install).

Following the instructions here (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-local), I have downloaded Docker Toolbox and successfully run the `docker run hello-world` command.

However, when I try to run the following code:

```
set "GCP_PROJECT_ID=YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
set "CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME=gcr.io/earthengine-project/datalab-ee:latest"
set "HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
set "WORKSPACE=%HOME%\workspace\datalab-ee"
mkdir "%WORKSPACE%"
cd %WORKSPACE%
```

I get the following error on the 5th line: `mkdir: cannot create directory '%WORKSPACE': Permission denied`.

Does anyone know what's causing this? I have only ever use Anaconda Prompt and am not used to the syntax of this terminal.

Also, just to clarify, I entered the correct project ID into the terminal for line 1, but have not shared it here.

Comment: Not every terminal program is Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I don't know what that means. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was using the Docker Quickstart Terminal. Switched to Windows Command Prompt and everything running fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add yourself to the docker user group.

Run the following command in your shell or terminal window:

sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}

where user is the google user with which I log in to the console, after executing the command it is necessary to restart the terminal.